# How to show Null Value when using SUM Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have issue with my script in SQL Server, i need to show Total of 3 Columns with NULL Values
[image: My Query]

here is my query :

```
SELECT 
    Bucket,
        (SELECT SUM (OutstandingPrincipal)  FROM example
        WHERE [status] = 'Covid')
    AS Covid,
        (SELECT SUM (OutstandingPrincipal) FROM example
        WHERE [status] LIKE '%Disbu%')
    AS Disburs_After,
        (SELECT SUM (OutstandingPrincipal) FROM example
        WHERE [status] = 'Non Covid')
    AS Non_Covid
FROM example
WHERE Bucket IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    Bucket
```

how is it possible? thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like a conditional aggregation or even PIVOT would do the trick, but what does your table Example look like?

Comment: You probably need to use `case` but without seeing your table schema and sample data I wouldn't know. [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your data correctly, no need for all those subqueries, you can just use `conditional aggregation`:

```
select bucket,
       sum(case when status = 'Covid' then OutstandingPrincipal end) as covid,
       sum(case when status like '%Disbu%' then OutstandingPrincipal end) as Disburs_After,
       sum(case when status = 'Non Covid' then OutstandingPrincipal end) as Non_Covid
from example
where bucket is not null
group by bucket
```